# different body background colors in different routes in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am making an admin panel with angular. when user opens the panel, it checks if user is authenticated or not. if not, it will be redirected to the login page.

each of the panel and the login components has different body background colors. problem is when angular redirects the user to the login page the background-color doesn't change.

I have to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` everywhere. I should not change that. but in case I tried to remove that and it still didn't work.
I also tried to use global style file, but same result.

I have some plan-b solutions but trying to find the best practice here.

The codes should not be necessary, but here is the simplified code :

```
// login.ts :
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

.

```
// login.scss :
body {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

and :

```
// panel.ts :
@Component({
    selector: 'app-panel',
    templateUrl: './panel.html',
    styleUrls: ['./panel.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.auth.isLogin()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
// panel.scss :
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: What if you change to `background` without `-color`?

Comment: @Oen44 I just tried it and it didn't work. :(

Comment: try `html { background-color: #777; }`

Comment: @Aragorn : it did not work.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz snippet which demonstrates the issue ?

Comment: @AminAdel the panel.scss and login.scss, are they part of the respective component? meaning, panel.scss is it similar to panel.component.style.css?

Comment: @Aragorn : check `@Component` ... panel.scss belongs to panel.ts component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add extra classes to `body` element and set different colors based on that class name. you need to use `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hooks like this :

```
// login.ts :
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('login');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('login');
}
```

then your style for this component will be :

```
// login.scss :
body.login {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

and of course for panel component :

```
// panel.ts :
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('panel');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('panel');
}
```

and the style :

```
// panel.scss :
body.panel {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: note that the body element can be directly accessed with `document.body` which is [more performant](https://jsbench.me/mmkk5eakt9)

Answer (score 2):

The question is about Angular 6, but I'm going to give a solution for Angular 9, just in case someone else will run into a similar problem.

The way I would do it is based on the routes. When defining the routes, you can add extra data, for example a class name.

When the route changes (i.e. user navigates from one route to another), the data from the active route can be used to set the class on the body tag.

### These are the steps to make this work

1. Update the styles.css (or styles.scss) to add different classes for body:

```
body {
  ...
}

body.red {
  background-color: #ff8181;
}

body.blue {
  background-color: #a0c3ee;
}
```

2. Update the routes to add extra data, specifying the body class name. Add an extra data property, like `bodyClass`. For the components where you are OK with the default class, you don't have to specify it:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
  { path: 'red', component: RedComponent, data: { bodyClass: 'red' } },
  { path: 'blue', component: BlueComponent, data: { bodyClass: 'blue' } }
];
```

3. Write the code to read the `bodyClass` and set the class to the body element when navigation between routes occurs. This needs to be done in only one place, in the `app.component.ts` and it's going to use the injected `ActivatedRoute` to get the extra data:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document, 
    private renderer: Renderer2, 
    private router: Router, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute))
      .pipe(map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
          route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return route;
      }))
      .pipe(filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'))
      .pipe(mergeMap((route) => route.data))
      .subscribe((event) => this.updateBodyClass(event.bodyClass));
  }

  private updateBodyClass(customBodyClass?: string) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.document?.body, 'class', '');
    if (customBodyClass) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.document?.body, customBodyClass);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rs1tai

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

to solve this problem i have add a body tag to the different components:

redpage.component.ts

```
<body>
    <h2> Red Page</h2>
</body>
```

greenpage.component.ts

```
<body>
    <h2> Green Page</h2>
</body>
```

and i use the following css :

redpage.component.css

```
body{
    background: red !important;
    height:100vh;
}
```

greenpage.component.css

```
body{
    background: green !important;
    height:100vh;
}
```

I hope this will help you